# How do I check a checkbox using selenium in Python3

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'd prefer to refrain from using xpaths unless it is indeed the only way to do it.
Here's the simple checkbox I'm playing with: [w3schools.checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked)

I want to check the "I have a bike". I tried calling the `find_element_by_name` method on `self.driver` but wihtout success and here's my miserable attempt to use xpaths:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class CheckBox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked'
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get(self.url)

    def check_I_have_a_bike(self):
        bike_xpath = ".//input[@value='Bike']" # seems pretty straightforward and simple
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(bike_xpath).click()
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print('Error: {error_message}'.format(error_message=e))

checker = CheckBox()
checker.check_I_have_a_bike()

`Error: Unable to locate element: .//input[@value='Bike']`
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target `input` field located inside an `iframe`. To handle checkbox you have to switch to `iframe` first:

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame("iframeResult")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(bike_xpath)
```

It should be also accessible by `name`:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name("vehicle")
```

but note that name `"vehicle"` applied to both checkboxes

Also you might need to use

```
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

to switch back from `iframe`

Comment: Hmmm it worked. Seems like I didn't play around with xpaths enough to work it out for meself. But there's no other way of doing it without first switching to the iframe, right?

Comment: `iframe` is another `HTML` document, that embedded in main document. So you should switch between main `DOM` and `iframe` `DOM` each time you need to handle appropriate element

Comment: Got it. Thank you a lot!